# How to get stream from Google+ REST API

Tags: rest, stream, google-plus

I have been browsing the Google Plus APIs lately and I can't seem to figure out if its possible to get the stream of posts of all those people who I have circled.

Like, for example, Twitter gives its home_timeline in the APIs.. Is there something similar in Google Plus?

I have read through the [Google+ API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) and even tried [Google's API explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1), but couldn't seem to figure out how to do it.

It's a very important feature of any API, which really shouldn't be missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google+ API does not currently provide a stream API. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=25).

Answer (score -1):

it's possible, at least your personal activities or the public activities of a specific person:  https://developers.google.com/+/api/