# Google+ api to get the home feed

Tags: google-plus

I need to get the posts user see on his home feed, in a json format. via google+ http api. Didn't find any public documentation about it, anyone know a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get stream from Google+ REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689305/how-to-get-stream-from-google-rest-api)

Answer (score 2):

Google+ does not provide a stream API or any method to view non-public posts.

Comment: But I can't see all public posts. All i retrieve is posts by myself.